# vuejs and ie browser problem with version

Tags: node.js, vue.js

how to make my app codify incompatibilities with ie. I'm using the vuejs and nodejs backend
I'm using babel but I still do not know how to use it correctly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i am using vue js but no work on ie

Comment: "No work" is too broad for others to be able to help you. Please, provide browser console errors and relevant code snippets.

Comment: my .babelrc {
    "presets":["es2015"]
} my scripts start   "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node app.js"
  },